# Custom field not showing in page layout

Tags: custom-field

I have successfully created a custom field with MetaData API but it it's not visible in lead page.

below is the code how I create it.

```
 public bool CreateCustomField_LongTextArea(SforceService binding) { bool Response = true; try {

            CustomField cf = new CustomField();
            cf.description = "Genral Information Notes";
            cf.fullName = "Lead.ActeolGeneralInfo__c";
            cf.label = "General Info";
            cf.typeSpecified = true;
            cf.length = 32768;
            cf.lengthSpecified = true;
            cf.visibleLines = 5;
            cf.visibleLinesSpecified = true;
            cf.type = FieldType.LongTextArea;



            MetadataService mBinding = new MetadataService();
            mBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new MetadataServiceRef.SessionHeader();
            mBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;
            mBinding.Url = binding.Url.Replace(@"/u/", @"/m/");


            MetadataServiceRef.SaveResult[] results = mBinding.createMetadata(new Metadata[] { cf });

            foreach (MetadataServiceRef.SaveResult s in results)
            {
                if (s.success)
                {
                    List<string> Profiles = new List<string>();
                Profiles.Add("Admin");
                MetadataServiceRef.Metadata[] ProfilesPerm = new MetadataServiceRef.Metadata[10];
                int Batch = 1;
                int ProfileIdx = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Profiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    MetadataServiceRef.Profile admin = new MetadataServiceRef.Profile();
                    admin.fullName = Profiles[i];
                    admin.custom = false;

                    MetadataServiceRef.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity fieldSec = new MetadataServiceRef.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity();
                    fieldSec.field = fullName;
                    fieldSec.editable = true;
                    admin.fieldPermissions = new MetadataServiceRef.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity[] { fieldSec };
                    ProfilesPerm[ProfileIdx] = admin;
                    ProfileIdx++;
                    if ((Batch * 10) - 1 == i || i == (Profiles.Count - 1))
                    {
                        MetadataServiceRef.SaveResult[] results123 = mBinding.updateMetadata(ProfilesPerm);
                        Array.Clear(ProfilesPerm, 0, ProfilesPerm.Length);
                        ProfileIdx = 0;
                        Batch++;
                    }
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error creating Lead: {0}", s.errors[0].message);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response = false;
        }
        return Response;
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!!!!!!

Comment: you need to add the new custom field to the page layout either manually or thru the metadata api. refer the addFieldToLayout method in this sample https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls

Comment: Thanks for response but the line below not worked. I haven't the method "getRecords"

Layout layout = (Layout) service.readMetadata("Layout", new String[] {"Test__c-Test Layout"}).getRecords()[0];